# Parse array of string in PLJSON oracle

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, pljson

I have to parse a array of string in my JSON with ORACLE dans PLJSON module.
I'm able to parse data without array like CLE,X,Y.. 
But when I want to get COLORS or REGROUPEMENT_COLORS, this return me nothing.

There is the code:

```
DECLARE
    obj json := json();
    obj_1 json := json();
    arr json_list := json_list();
    test varchar2(255);

BEGIN

    obj := json('{
  "DASHBOARD": {
    "userUid": "",
    "DATA_DASHBOARD": [
      {
        "CLE": "TESTTEST",
        "X": "",
        "Y": "",
        "COL": "",
        "ROW": "",
        "CLASSCOLOR": "",
        "COLORS": ["df","df"],
        "REGROUPEMENT_ID": "",
        "REGROUPEMENT_TEXT": "",
        "REGROUPEMENT_CLASSCOLOR": "",
        "REGROUPEMENT_X": "",
        "REGROUPEMENT_Y": "",
        "REGROUPEMENT_COL": "",
        "REGROUPEMENT_ROW": "",
        "REGROUPEMENT_COLORS": ["d","df"]
      }
    ]
  }
}');


    obj_1 :=json(obj.get('DASHBOARD'));


    arr := json_list(obj_1.get('DATA_DASHBOARD'));

     test := json_ext.get_string(json(arr.get(1)), 'REGROUPEMENT_COLORS');

    DBMS(test);


END;
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REGROUPEMENT_COLORS` is an array, not a string, so `json_ext.get_string()` is not returning anything. If you want a string then get `REGROUPEMENT_COLORS[1]` or `REGROUPEMENT_COLORS[2]`; if you want the array then use `json_ext.get_json_list` rather than `json_ext.get_string`.

To output a string use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` not `DBMS`.

If you are using `json_ext` then you can use the full path.

**PL/SQL**:

```sql
DECLARE
  obj pljson := pljson(
    '{
      "DASHBOARD": {
        "userUid": "",
        "DATA_DASHBOARD": [
          {
            "CLE": "TESTTEST",
            "X": "",
            "Y": "",
            "COL": "",
            "ROW": "",
            "CLASSCOLOR": "",
            "COLORS": ["df","df"],
            "REGROUPEMENT_ID": "",
            "REGROUPEMENT_TEXT": "",
            "REGROUPEMENT_CLASSCOLOR": "",
            "REGROUPEMENT_X": "",
            "REGROUPEMENT_Y": "",
            "REGROUPEMENT_COL": "",
            "REGROUPEMENT_ROW": "",
            "REGROUPEMENT_COLORS": ["d","df"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }'
  );
  test varchar2(255);
  arr  pljson_list;
BEGIN
  test := pljson_ext.get_string( obj, 'DASHBOARD.DATA_DASHBOARD[1].REGROUPEMENT_COLORS[1]');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(test);
  arr := pljson_ext.get_json_list( obj, 'DASHBOARD.DATA_DASHBOARD[1].REGROUPEMENT_COLORS');
  arr.print;
  FOR i IN 1 .. arr.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( arr.get_string(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*(Note: the objects/packages have the `pl` prefix as db<>fiddle does not allow creating synonyms; you should be able to remove those prefixes if your implementation has the appropriate synonyms created.)*

**Outputs**:

> ```
> d
> ["d", "df"]
> d
> df
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7aeafc92a94a5f0e3581c55f7098ebca)*

Comment: Hey , Thanks ! It whats I need  , but I want to make a loop to get all value one per one (I make an insert in myse DB).How can I do this ?

Comment: @DEVLOGIN Updated to show a loop through the `json_list`.