# How to convert JSON into XML in Oracle 10g

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I work on Oracle 10g where it's possible to use the built-in functions for handling XML documents but not JSON datatype bacause as far as I know that is only possible from Oracle 12c on.
Aside from installing the APEX_JSON package, has anyone here some plsql or other ways to convert JSON into XML and eventually XML into JSON? Because whenever I have to load an external JSON file into a CLOB column I'll have then to convert it into an XML for managing it by using the XML built-in function in Oracle 10g.

Thanks in advance!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pljson](https://github.com/pljson/pljson) package to parse JSON data.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047082/parse-array-of-string-in-pljson-oracle/59050086#59050086) gives an example of how to parse JSON and extract values using the pljson package. Like this:

```sql
DECLARE
  obj pljson := pljson(
    '{
      "DASHBOARD": {
        "userUid": "",
        "DATA_DASHBOARD": [
          {
            "CLE": "TESTTEST",
            "X": "",
            "Y": "",
            "COL": "",
            "ROW": "",
            "CLASSCOLOR": "",
            "COLORS": ["df","df"],
            "REGROUPEMENT_ID": "",
            "REGROUPEMENT_TEXT": "",
            "REGROUPEMENT_CLASSCOLOR": "",
            "REGROUPEMENT_X": "",
            "REGROUPEMENT_Y": "",
            "REGROUPEMENT_COL": "",
            "REGROUPEMENT_ROW": "",
            "REGROUPEMENT_COLORS": ["d","df"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }'
  );
  test varchar2(255);
  arr  pljson_list;
BEGIN
  test := pljson_ext.get_string( obj, 'DASHBOARD.DATA_DASHBOARD[1].REGROUPEMENT_COLORS[1]');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(test);
  arr := pljson_ext.get_json_list( obj, 'DASHBOARD.DATA_DASHBOARD[1].REGROUPEMENT_COLORS');
  arr.print;
  FOR i IN 1 .. arr.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( arr.get_string(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*(Note: the objects/packages have the pl prefix as db<>fiddle does not allow creating synonyms; you should be able to remove those prefixes if your implementation has the appropriate synonyms created.)*